# How to handle backslash(\) in filename or folder name. (Qt, Unix)

Tags: qt, unix, cross-platform

I am using mac to write platform crossing code. 
In Unix (including macos), backslash is valid for file name or folder name.
In my code, I need to consider QString may be from Windows or Unix. 
So how do I decide if some part of my string is a file name or 
folder name other than a path.

I have these special cases.

\.jpg
\a\b
\
\a.jpg

I cannot use toNativeSeparator() because the function will convert my non-separator backslash to slash.

So anyone have idea how to handle these corner cases? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Backslash is not valid character for cross-platform names (it is a separator under win). So you need to write your own code with your own logic to handle such cases.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, backslash cannot be cross-platform names, however, it can be used in mac or linux.                                                                   I want to handle the case path1 + path2.                                                   In Windows, there should be no problem, I can convert all separators to backslash.                                                                                                 In Unix,  since paths can contain backslash standing for windows path or Unix file or folder name, I have no idea to decide if I should convert.

Comment: You need to write your own code to concatenate strings. It's very easy.